# pull custom fields values from wp-database in a nested foreach loop

Tags: customization, wpdb

I am trying to display custom fields on my template values of which i am pulling from postmeta table
doing something wrong with a loop or not writing the foreach args correctly not sure whats the problem
pastebin link for the code http://pastebin.com/eyPD6Qws

basically i want to display 15 div's with 3 cols so to say (name, photo,region)

To make it more simple to explain exactly what i am doing is
using a plugin called flutter(yes i know it is dead now) but it works for me i am creating profiles for say agents 
there individual pages work perfectly 
but now i want to create a page where i display small brief of everyone's profile (like we have portfolio pages) 
for which i have created a code(which can be seen here http://pastebin.com/eyPD6Qws)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my problem, finally sorted it (happy-face)
{

```
            global $wpdb;  
        $broker_names = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'B_name'  ORDER BY  meta_id DESC  ", ARRAY_A);  
        $b_region = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'Region' ORDER BY  meta_id DESC ", ARRAY_A);

            $b_photo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'Photo' ORDER BY  meta_id DESC ", ARRAY_A); 


                for($d=0; $d<=count($b_names); $d++)
                {
                    echo '<div id="b-group"><dl class="b-badge">';
                    echo '<dt class="b-image">';
                    echo '<img src='.get_site_url().'/wp-content/files_flutter/'.$broker_photo[$d]['meta_value'].' /></dt> ';
                    echo '<dd class="b-name"><span>'. $b_names[$d]['meta_value'].'</span>'; 
                    echo '</dd><dd class="b-region">';
                    $r_region = $b_region[$d]['meta_value'];
                    $new_region = unserialize($r_region);
                    echo '  '.$new_region[0].'</dd> ';  
                    echo '</dl></div>';

                }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should use WP's built-in class [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to pull the information and I am sure that will alone simplify your entire process.

Comment: Puneet, i am not much of a php coder, if you can explain a bit looking at my pastebin code i have added up, would be of much help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop. Inside the loop and call the meta data with the basic template function [`get_post_custom()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_custom/).

```
// Short'n'dirty...
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $meta = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );

    echo "\n<hr />{$GLOBALS['post']->post_title} Custom Data:\n<pre>".var_export( $meta, true ).'</pre>';

endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: na it gives an error and could you explain how is it exactly pulling the 3 values i need to display

Comment: Ehm... "gives an error" is like saying "the sky got a color" - it doesn't help determining what the problem is. Please add a full error output + description. Further: Have you checked wher "Flutter" saves the post meta data - maybe you are wrong with postmeta table? Also: You're talking about profile data. Are you sure, that we're not talking about user meta data?

Comment: Ok so gives an error (page doesnt display at all), yes it works file (my query (Code) which i have written and pulls the content and everything which i want to display) as i stated my problem is the loop, or foreach(args) which i a writing and calling three times for 3 different values i tried using array.combine, and other functions like that but they dont work in my case, (please take a look at the pastebin code i have added in my question)

Comment: How the result should come 
box 1 - name1, photo1, region1
box2 - name2,photo2,region2
box3 - name3, photo3,region3

right now after my looping and everything 
it is coming as
box1 - name1,photo1,region1
box2 - name1,photo1,region1
box3 - name1,photo1,region1

i know my data pulling query is right because if i dont and break, or make for loops it displays all the content which i am pulling but not formatted + sort of endless loop

Comment: The Post title comes three times each?

Comment: anyways thanks got it fixed, instead of foreach i just had to call a for

Comment: @robin Than add this as answer and mark it as solution two days after that. Else it stays filed under "unanswered questions". Thanks.

Comment: Yup wanted to do that but since it gave me a notification saying cant add your own answer for atleast 8hrs

Comment: Then just do it tomorrow :)